# SQL SELECT QUERY COUNT

Tags: sql

I'm new to this so bear with me.

I'm trying to create a select query from a `Movie` database. Amongst other tables there is a `Role` table that features information such as `roleID, roleName, gender, actorID, movieID`. An actor can have many roles in different movies.

I am trying to create the query so it will tell me how many actors have three or more roles in the database.

I've tried a few solutions and they output data just not sure if it is right.

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT actorID) FROM Role WHERE actorID >= 3

SELECT COUNT (actorID) FROM Role GROUP BY movieID HAVING COUNT (actorID) >=3
```

Comment: First one says only want to count any results with ActorID >= 3, which isn't what you're after!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try something like:

```
select actorID, count(*)
from Roles  
group by actorID  
having count (*) >= 3
```

If you want to retrieve other properties about the actor you add those to both the select and group by clauses

Comment: He wanted the count, not the list of them!

Comment: @Bridge: he wasn't explicit about what he wanted to retrieve, just the criteria for finding them. I've added count anyway for info.

Comment: Thanks, used this one, seams to tell me the actor ID and how many roles each one has :-)

Comment: @KAJ And I quote: "so it will tell me **how many** actors" - that would have inferred count to me!

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Role 
GROUP BY actorid
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following

```
SELECT actorID, COUNT(actorID) 
FROM Role 
GROUP BY actorID 
HAVING COUNT (actorID) >=3
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this ..

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM (SELECT actorID FROM Roles GROUP BY actorID HAVING COUNT(*)>=3) AS actor;
```

This query return number of actors who have three or more roles in the database.

Answer (score 1):

your second query is almost correct.

You need to group by actorId, because you want to count them. You have put movieId, which makes no sense in that case.

```
SELECT COUNT (*) as actorRoles
FROM Role 
GROUP BY actorId
HAVING actorRoles >=3;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select   count(*) 
from     Role
where    actorID in 
         (
             select    actorID 
             from      Role 
             group by  actorID 
             having    count(actorID) > 3
         )
```